# Add Two Binary Numbers Recursively, w/o Bitwise Operations; Java Homework

Tags: java

I think I've gotten mostly to a solution for a homework problem.

This is for a 201 CS class. Right now I just want to get the logic right. At present, it doesn't operate as intended, but it's close.

We don't want to use .toBinary, bitwise, or anything else. We also haven't been taught stringBuilder, so I'd like to avoid using it.

There's a System.out.println(); within the method which provides the correct answer if you read the console from bottom to top.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(addBin(1100111011,1101110011));
}

public static String addBin(int num1,int num2){

    String result = "";

    if(num1 > 0 || num2 > 0){

        int part1 = num1%10, part2 = num2%10;
        int rem1 = num1/10, rem2 = num2/10;

        result += Integer.toString((part1 + part2)%2);

        //System.out.println(result);

        int carry = (part1 + part2) /2;

        addBin(rem1 + carry, rem2);

        return result;

    }

    return result;

}
```

So, this example adds 1100111011 and 1101110011 with the output

```
0
1
1
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
1
0
```

when the correct answer is 11010101110.

I'm having trouble understanding how to properly "pop" the "result" part properly. Could you please help me understand this process, possibly within the context of this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you want `System.out.println(addBin(0b1100111011,0b1101110011));`?

Comment: I do not. Those are "binary" numbers ostensibly received directly from user input. Like, I should be able to get those numbers in a Scanner from somewhere.

Comment: `addBin` returns a value; you should use that return value. It might help to not create a `result` variable, and instead just consider the two values `addBin(rem1 + carry, rem2)` and `Integer.toString((part1 + part2)%2)`.

Comment: Got it!

Thanks for your help. I was misunderstanding how to do that.

`String result = addBin(rem1 + carry, rem2) + Integer.toString((part1 + part2)%2);`

Comment: Use string to get users input not int!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from your output, you are getting the correct result in the reverse order but you are not appending any of your older result to the ones that are being currently computed.

Inside your if condition, you are calling the addBin() function but you are not using the result that it gives anywhere. Just change that line to the following:

```
result = addBin(rem1 + carry, rem2)+result;
```

That should effective append all your results in front of the current answer so that you do not get the result in backwards direction. Hope this helps.